# update a marker on Google map using PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, google-maps-api-3

i am new to web developing and i need a help please.
this is my code it suppose to update the marker location by the gotten coordinates from database

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


Markers();
function Markers() {

 var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>;
 var myvar2 = <?php echo json_encode($long); ?>;
 document.write(myvar ,myvar2 );

    markers = [
    {
        "title": 'Aksa Beach',
        "lat": myvar,
        "lng": myvar2,
        "description": 'Driver Name: Mohamed'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Juhu Beach',
        "lat": '19.0883595',
        "lng": '72.82652380000002',
        "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favourite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
        "lat": '18.9542149',
        "lng": '72.81203529999993',
        "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
        "lat": '18.979006',
        "lng": '72.83388300000001',
        "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
        "lat": '19.2147067',
        "lng": '72.91062020000004',
        "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
    }
    ];
   //return markers;
    }


    window.onload = function () {
        LoadMap();
    };

    var map;
    var marker;
    function LoadMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        SetMarker(0);
    };

    //while loop to call to update lan/long
    function SetMarker(position) {
        //Remove previous Marker.
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        //Set Marker on Map.
        var data = markers[position];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });

        //Create and open InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    };
</script>



<div>
    <label for="rbMarker0">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker0" name="rbMarker" value="0" onclick="SetMarker(this.value)"
          checked="checked"  />Driver Name: Mohamed </label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker1">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker1" name="rbMarker" value="1" onclick="SetMarker(this.value)" />Juhu
        Beach</label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker2">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker2" name="rbMarker" value="2" onclick="SetMarker(this.value)" />Girgaum
        Beach</label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker3">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker3" name="rbMarker" value="3" onclick="SetMarker(this.value)" />Jijamata
        Udyan</label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker4">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker4" name="rbMarker" value="4" onclick="SetMarker(this.value)" />Sanjay
        Gandhi National Park</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 400px; height: 500px">
</div>



<?php 

  include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/connection.php');

while (1)
{
                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `test2` WHERE  `ID` = 298";
                  $res = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

                 while( $row = $res->fetch_row() ){
                $long = $row[1];
                $lat = $row[2] ;
                 }


echo "<script> Markers(); </script>"; 
}

?>
```

There's two problems:

- first:variables `myvar`,`myvar2` are always `null` although I got data from the database .
- second:the map never load only , only if I removed the "while(1)" from the PHP code.

[here is a image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etjws.png)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a scripting language, the target is to recieve a request, handle it, produce output and finish the script then. If you don't finish the script, the browser will always think your script isn't finished and will show that the page is still loading.

A drawing loop with while(true) or while(1) you will close to never see in php.
And you declared the variables $long and $lat at the end of the script, their value is null at the beginning, because you never declared them before.

To create cleaner code, try to seperate php, html and javascript. Try to avoid changing things outside the function scope, and declare it if a parameter is changed in the function.

```
<?php
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/connection.php'); //there is also __DIR__

//while (1)
//{
                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `test2` WHERE  `ID` = 298";
                  $res = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

                 while( $row = $res->fetch_row() ){
                $long = $row[1];
                $lat = $row[2] ;
                 }



//echo "<script> Markers(); </script>"; 
//}

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myvar = <?php echo $lat;?>;
// we dont' need json encode, because we want the value directly echo json_encode($lat);      
var myvar2 = <?php echo $long;?>;
//json_encode($long); 
 //what should happen here? like this you replace the whole html document with myvar and myvar2 document.write(myvar ,myvar2 );





    markers = [
    {
        "title": 'Aksa Beach',
        "lat": myvar,
        "lng": myvar2,
        "description": 'Driver Name: Mohamed'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Juhu Beach',
        "lat": '19.0883595',
        "lng": '72.82652380000002',
        "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favourite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
        "lat": '18.9542149',
        "lng": '72.81203529999993',
        "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
        "lat": '18.979006',
        "lng": '72.83388300000001',
        "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
        "lat": '19.2147067',
        "lng": '72.91062020000004',
        "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
    }
    ];

    var map;
    var marker;

    window.onload = function () {
        map = LoadMap();
    };


    function LoadMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        SetMarker(0, map);
        return map; // try to not change variables outside the function scope
    };

    //while loop to call to update lan/long
    function SetMarker(position, map) {
        //Remove previous Marker.
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        //Set Marker on Map.
        var data = markers[position];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });

        //Create and open InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    };
</script>



<div>
    <label for="rbMarker0">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker0" name="rbMarker" value="0" onclick="SetMarker(this.value, map)"
          checked="checked"  />Driver Name: Mohamed </label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker1">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker1" name="rbMarker" value="1" onclick="SetMarker(this.value, map)" />Juhu
        Beach</label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker2">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker2" name="rbMarker" value="2" onclick="SetMarker(this.value, map)" />Girgaum
        Beach</label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker3">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker3" name="rbMarker" value="3" onclick="SetMarker(this.value, map)" />Jijamata
        Udyan</label><br />
    <label for="rbMarker4">
        <input type="radio" id="rbMarker4" name="rbMarker" value="4" onclick="SetMarker(this.value, map)" />Sanjay
        Gandhi National Park</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 400px; height: 500px">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok,thats Good..but the coordinates is getting updates every second on the database so i need to access the DB to get the new lat&long every second and update the Marker position.

Comment: most easy way: reload it: window.setTimeout(1000, function(e){window.location.reload(true);});

or you ajaxify it. you have a seperate php script which outputs the coordinates as json, and a html/js file, which sends a request to the php script every second and then redraws the marker (with jquery and $.ajax)